# Adding argument to this in an ADT

Tags: java, addition, adt

I need to make an add(Length) method that return a new length that is equal in size to the sum of the sizes of this length and the argument.  I am unsure whether I need to return a double or Length and how to add

```
public class Length implements Comparable<Length>{

    private final double length; //private!  Do NOT add a getter

    // This constructor must remain private
    private Length(double l){
        length = l;
    }
    public double add(Length l){
        return ;
    }
    public double subtract(Length l){

    }
    public double scale(double d){

    }
    public double divide(Length l){

    }
    public double Length(Position one, Position two){

    }
    // TODO: For all constants, have a line:
    // public static final Length ... = new Length(...);


    // Use the @Override annotation on all methods
    // That override a superclass method.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        //TODO
    }

    // If you are overriding a method from an interface, then Java 5
    // says you CANNOT use Override, but Java 6 says you MAY.  Either is OK.
    // @Override
    public int compareTo(Length other) {
        //TODO
    }

    // TODO Write the rest of the methods for this class, and
    // the other two classes.

}
```

Comment: You should return a new `Length` object which has a `length` variable equal to the sum of the current `Length` and the one passed as an argument.

Comment: Are you trying to create an immutable class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement, but typically you'd want to return a new `Length` object.

```
public Length add(Length other){
    // check that other is not null
    return new Length(this.length + other.length);
}
```

You would do something similar for all the other mathematical methods.

As Rohit has stated in their comment, this makes your class immutable since there is no method that can modify the `length` field (but instead return a new `Length` object).